# Can we do association between An Associative Class and a normal class?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

so i'm wondering if this relation is possible to do ?

[image: Class Diagram Image]

And thank you for your time, good day/night!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course. An association can be made between any two classes. And an association class is just a `Class`. As stated on p. 197 of the UML specs:

> An Association classifies a set of tuples representing links between typed instances. An AssociationClass is both an Association and a Class.